# Phase equilibrium

Tags: thermodynamics, phase-transition, equilibrium

For a 2 phase closed system: $$d(nG)=(nV)dP-(nS)dT+\Sigma\mu_idn_i$$
now the question is, when we can use formula, $$d(nG)=(nV)dP-(nS)dT,$$ for the above system, instead of the first formula, and why?
In my textbook, is said tath we can use the second formula when the system is in equilibrium. But why we can't use that when the system isn't in equilibrium?
In the textbook it said: $$d(nG)^\alpha=(nV^\alpha)dP-(nS^\alpha)dT+\Sigma\mu_i^\alpha dn_i^\alpha$$  and $$d(nG)^\beta=(nV^\beta)dP-(nS^\beta)dT+\Sigma\mu_i^\beta dn_i^\beta$$  where $\alpha$ represent one phase and $\beta$ represent the other one.
Now summation yields:  $$d(nG)^\alpha+d(nG)^\beta=d(nG)$$  $$(nV^\alpha+nV^\beta)dP-(nS^\alpha+nS^\beta)dT=(nV)dP-(nS)dT$$  so we have:$$d(nG)=(nV)dP-(nS)dT+\Sigma\mu_i^\alpha dn_i^\alpha+\Sigma\mu_i^\beta dn_i^\beta\tag{I} $$  and now it said that in equilibrium state also :
$$d(nG)=(nV)dP-(nS)dT\tag{II}$$  and by equating $(I)$ with $(II)$:
$$\Sigma\mu_i^\alpha dn_i^\alpha+\Sigma\mu_i^\beta dn_i^\beta=0$$ for a closed system:$$n_i=n_i^\alpha+n_i^\beta=C \Rightarrow dn_i=0 \Rightarrow dn_i^\alpha+dn_i^\beta=0$$ so:$$\Sigma(\mu_i^\alpha - \mu_i^\beta)dn_i^\alpha=0$$ and we can conclude that $\mu_i^\alpha-\mu_i^\beta=0$ and so $\mu_i^\alpha=\mu_i^\beta$ in equilibrium state.  now my question is, why in equilibrium state we can use $(II)$ ,instead of $(I)$?

Answer (score 1):

Try using the first equation and see what happens.

Your book should have a modifier in front of the word "equilibrium". Specifically, dropping the last term is only valid when the system is in *chemical* equilibrium. When it is in chemical equilibrium, chemical potential term is *by definition* equal in each phase. If it is equal in both phases, they cancel out and you don't have to worry about them.

Consider a practical example, a water purification system using reverse osmosis. We have (in a simplified version) a bucket with a membrane in the middle. On each side of the membrane we have 10% concentrated salt water at room temperature and pressure. The membrane allows the water through but not the salt. In this state, all three terms cancel out because the pressure, temperature, and chemical potential are all in equilibrium. Therefore, nothing happens.

If we increase the pressure on the left side, as in a reverse osmosis system, the first term becomes imbalanced. Water flows from the high pressure side through the membrane to the low pressure side. As the water flows, the concentration of salt on the left side goes up while the concentration of salt on the right side goes down. The water will continue flowing until the chemical potential term balances the pressure term. At that point, the whole system will be in equilibrium again.

Notice that in our example the temperatures were always constant so we ignored the middle term. You could do a similar example using water and steam where you increase the pressure and fixed the volume. This time though, the temperature would change. In that system you could ignore the chemical potential term.

Overall, use the full equation and see which terms you can set to zero.

Comment: I want to know why in equilibrium we can use $(II)$ instead of $(I)$

Comment: I thought thats what I answered. As you showed in your edit, the chemical potentials are equal when the two phases are in chemical equilibrium, which is the definition of chemical equilibrium. The terms cancel out and you can ignore them. Can you explain more what is still unclear?

Comment: why in other state where we don't have equilibrium, we can't write $d(nG)=(nV)dP-(nS)dT$? and if we can so we can conclude that $\mu_i^\alpha=\mu_i^\beta$, for states other than equilibrium state, which is not correct.